# JavaScript object literals syntax error

Tags: javascript

The following code produces a syntax error in Chrome and Firefox, but not Node.js:

```
{"hello": 1}
```

However, the following code works everywhere:

```
var x = {"hello": 1}
```

Also, the following works everywhere:

```
{hello: 1}
```

What is the explanation for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [NodeJS REPL evaluates code as an expression](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/2900f0778a850ada6463e07de9725f9022029e67/lib/repl.js#L251-L253), by wrapping the code in parentheses, causing `{"hello":1}` to be `({"hello":1})` which is parsed successfully as an object literal.

Usually and elsewhere (in Chrome/Firefox's console), the curly braces are parsed as the delimiters of a block, like:

```
/*imagine if (true) */ {
    "hello": 1 // <-- What's this syntax? It's meaningless.
}
```

`{hello:1}` parses successfully, because `hello` in this context has the meaning of a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

```
/*imagine if (true) */ {
    hello: 1;
} //        ^-- Automatic Semicolon Insertion
```

Answer (score 13):

The first example is not an object literal, it is a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). Blocks contain statements. The squence *String literal*, *colon*, *Number literal* is not a valid statement.

The second example is an object literal.

The third example is also a block, but you have replaced the string literal and colon with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (which is allowed, but is pointless as there is no loop).

Context is important in JavaScript.