# Why does this object literal cause a syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I´m kind of confused as to why I can assign the following object literal:

```
var x = { "a" : true };
```

While changing it to a simple statement:

```
{ "a" : true };
```

Will cause `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in Firefox and Chrome (it works as expected in Node).

Comment: JS supports braces, so alone the syntax is ambiguous. note that the braces don't do anything (yet), but they are officially legit even in ES3

Comment: It gets parsed as a block. This is a duplicate, but i'm too tired to find it right now.

Comment: also, it's a syntax error in node as well, you must have tried on the repl, but in a file, it will throw.

Comment: What would you expect that statement to do?  It looks like merely an expression to me.  Why it's a syntax error, I'm sure not, but "Unexpected token" seems reasonable because I wouldn't expect this syntax.

Comment: Why does it get parsed as a block while `{ a: true }` does not? And why does Node handle it differently than chrome? Don't they use the same parser?

Comment: `a: true` is a labelled expression. wrapping braces on it doesn't change that. Both node and Chrome use V8

Comment: It gets parsed as a block, and `a:` is a label, but `"a":` is just a string in the wrong place

Comment: What's important is the very first token of the statement. That is how the parser decides what it's going to expect. When the first token is `{` it decides it's going to parse a statement block.

Comment: Note that `{ a: true }` is OK because it's a valid statement in a block.

Comment: @Pointy: well, it's only a block in ES6, so to be precise, it's just a labeled something for now...

Comment: This explains quite a bit, I was expecting the parser to assume it was dealing with an object literal when it encountered brackets not preluded by a `function`, `if`, `else`,  `with`, `switch` construct. I was also not expecting the parser to differentiate between quoted and unquoted keys.

Comment: *"I was expecting the parser to assume it was dealing with an object literal when it encountered brackets not preluded by..."*. A block is its own syntactic element. It is used to group a set of statements. It's not actually part of the `if` or `with` statement. *"I was also not expecting the parser to differentiate between quoted and unquoted keys."*  It doesn't. `{ a: true }` is still parsed as a block. The issue is simply that `foo: bar` (label + identifier) is a valid statement, while `"foo": bar` (string literal + : punctuator (+ identifier)) is not.

Comment: @dandavis: *"it's only a block in ES6"* Uh? Blocks exist since ES1.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for the clarification. I had never really reflected on the fact that "bare" blocks existed in js since the are pretty much useless.

Comment: Except for `if` statements and loops ;) But you are right, they don't have much use outside of that (and thus not very common).... until now. With ES6, blocks create scope, just like in other languages.

Comment: @FelixKling: so what features are in/of these "blocks" you speak of? i can't seem to divine a test that can detect their presence/absence (without toString), am i missing something? if they cannot be detected, they cannot be used, and if they cannot be used, are they then really "blocks" like in other languages? to me, "block" means something other than extraneous or stylistic symbols... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming) for info i can agree with to see where i'm coming from.

Comment: @dandavis: They work pretty much like in other languages I believe. They don't create scope until now but they let you use a list of statements where a single statement is expected. The definition is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1. Compare the output of these two programs with and without a block: `if(false) console.log('inside block'); console.log('where am I?');` and `if(false) { console.log('inside block'); console.log('where am I?'); }`

Comment: @FelixKling: yeah, i'm not talking about IF statements or loops, etc. everyone knows about those effects, or should.  but i mean the kind of blocks in the OP (ex `{var a=1;}`), which afaik, have never behaved like other languages, and without `let`, still don't even in ES6. i think we both know the same thing, i was just wondering/hoping if there was some archaic/noticeable side-effect only a jedi like you could name... it's not everyday i learn something about JS, and i was hoping this could be one of those days... cheers. when i heard "blocks exit", for a tiny moment i was like "they do??!?"

Comment: @dandavis: No you are right, before ES6 there doesn't really seem to be an advantage to use blocks outside of `if`, `for` etc, sorry to disappoint you. But nonetheless, they are blocks, at least in the "scope" of JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript object literals syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298912/javascript-object-literals-syntax-error)

Here is a similar answer (assuming you used the REPL).  Basically Node will wrap the code in parentheses, thus parsing it successfully as an object literal.

```
{"hello":1} to be ({"hello":1})
```

Comment: no, it's not legit even to node.js... save a file with just `{ "a" : true }` as test.js, run `node test.js` and see if it's not an error (it is)

Comment: This is wrong, Node want wrap it in parentheses, but the REPL will wrap all code in parentheses, so there it wouldn't throw, but not really because it's suddenly valid JS.

Comment: Right; it's a REPL thing, but I think that's what the answerer meant here. (Being generous.)

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean.  I just assumed he did it this way since he was able to get it to work as he stated.