# Why are there differences between the node REPL and node script running when evaluating these expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, read-eval-print-loop, ecma

Why is there a difference between how Node REPL and the Node engine operating on a script interpret the following expression: `{...a}`?

I'm running node `v8.3.0` (discovered by running `node -v`) and have found an odd difference between the command line interpretation and script interpretation of spread operators.

Consider the following:

```
$ node -v
v8.3.0
$ node
```

(Getting the version of node and then running the node interpreter)

```
> const a = {foo: 'bar'};
undefined
> {...a};
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

(Creating an object literal and storing it in `const a`. Then, creating another object literal and filling with a `spread operator` on `a`.

So far so good. But if you create a `file.js`:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' };
{...a};
```

and run `> node file.js`, the result is a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`.

I might be answering my own question, but my current operating theory is that Node normally interprets `{` and `}` as a block of executable code, whereas the Node live interpreter is looking primarily for standalone expressions. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17298992/2848296) answer implies that everything gets wrapped in parens, which I doubt because multi-line code blocks are possible, but he's probably on the right track).

But if this is the case, why is it that `{ foo: 'bar' }` (standalone) evaluates without error in both REPL and a Node script?

The following executes without error in both REPL and a Node script:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[...a]
{foo: 'bar'}
```

But this fails in Node:

```
{...b}
```

What difference does the spread operator introduce?

---

**Edit**: Per [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy),  `{foo: 'bar'}` **does** evaluate standalone, but `{ foo: 'bar', sna: 'fu' }` **does not**. Node interprets the code between the braces as a code block, and `foo: 'bar'` is a valid Javascript expression, while `...a` and `foo: 'bar', sna: 'fu'` are not.

Comment: When you hit enter in the REPL, I guess it expects an expression and probably does something similar to wrapping the statement in parens. edit: [yes, that's what happens according to Axel Rauschmayer](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all has to do with how a **statement** is parsed. A statement (not an *expression*) that begins with a `{` is a statement block. When `{` appears in an expression, it introduces an object literal.

The statement:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

is syntactically correct but semantically different when interpreted as a statement and when interpreted as an expression. In the former case, it's the block statement:

```
{
   foo: 'bar'
}
```

which is a block containing one statement, the labeled expression `'bar'`. It is not an object literal.

The expression `{...a}` fails when `{` introduces a statement block because `...a` cannot itself be parsed as a statement.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label interesting... confirmed that `{foo: 'bar', sna: 'fu'}` does not evaluate.