# () brackets, what does it do in the statement of ({__proto__: []} instanceof Array) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, the following gives an error:

```js
{ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array;
```

If I surround it in `(brackets)` it has no error:

```js
({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array);
```

Why is this?

Comment: because `{}` can mean two things, block of code or object ... you want object, so you wrap it in `()` to do so (that's the quick layman's explanation - documentation will describe it better)

Comment: But the bracket ) at the end of instanceof Array, not the {__proto__: []}. What is the difference? @JaromandaX

Comment: hmmm, true dat - probably same deal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object literals syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298912/javascript-object-literals-syntax-error)

Comment: The answer below explains it well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the interpreter sees a `{`, by default, it will think that you're declaring a new block, such as

```js
{
  console.log('foo');
}
```

As a result:

```js
{
  __proto__: []
} instanceof Array
```

doesn't make much sense - you can't `instanceof` a block.

But when it's wrapped in parentheses, the interpreter knows to expect a *value* inside the parentheses, not a block - so it evaluates everything inside as an *expression* instead, and (properly) parses `{ __proto__: [] }` as an object.

This is exactly the same reason why, when destructuring to *already assigned variables*, you have to put parentheses around the line:

```js
let x, y;
({x, y} = { x: 'foo', y: 'bar'});
console.log('done ' + x);
```

works, but it doesn't without the `()`:

```js
let x, y;
{x, y} = { x: 'foo', y: 'bar'};
console.log('done ' + x);
```