# Evaluating an object literal with multiple keys results in SyntaxError in Firefox JS console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox putting this in the console works almost as expected. It evaluates to `123` instead of `{hello: 123}` but it does not produce an error.

```
{hello: 123}
// -> 123
```

However, if I add more than one key I get a syntax error:

```
{hello: 123, asdf: true}
// -> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
```

Assigning this to a local variable makes it work without error:

```
var myobj = {hello: 123, asdf: true}
// -> undefined
```

All of this works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox (68.0.2 (64-Bit)). What is Firefox doing differently compared to Chrome?

Comment: Try `({hello: 123, asdf: true})` - without the parentheses that's a *block*, not an object literal expression (and `hello:` is a *label* not a property name). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298912/javascript-object-literals-syntax-error.

Answer (score 2):

First one is a block of code with label, which is a valid syntax

```
 {hello: 123}
```

Whereas second one is invalid syntax because you can't use labeled statement, two label statement need to separated by `;` or new line

```
 {hello: 123
 asdf: true}
```

This will not throw error ASI will add `;`
or you can use

```
{hello: 123;
 asdf: true}
```

Or you can make it as expression using ()

```
 ({hello: 123, asdf: true})
```